# Opening directories in HTML

Tags: html

In some websites, I see links that look like this:

```
<a href="directory/">Link</a>
```

The link doesn't go to an html file, but a folder (I believe). I was wondering if this has any purpose, and how to do this. Is there a default file to open when opening a directory? Because when I try something like this, I click the link, then I see a list of files in that folder, and I have to click on the proper link.

Everywhere I look, it says you should do links like this:

```
<a href="directory/link.htm">Link</a>
```

Should I just let it go? I'm awfully curious.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 4):

This is something that is controlled by the web server. Some will look for a file called `default.htm`, others will look for `index.html`. It's usually configurable, and sometimes the server may look for any of a number of variations of `index` or `default`.

If such a file is not found, the server will often display a directory listing of all the files found in that folder, but usually that's not a good idea for security reasons. Again, this is something that can be controlled in the settings for the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My site right now isn't on a server, just my client while I develop it. Maybe that's the issue. I'll just link directly to the files. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean you're just using `file://` urls on your local machine, then that makes perfect sense. As far as I know, that will always display a directory listing when you're linking to a folder.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing directory listing is VERY dangerous and ill-advised practice. You should hide real directory structure of your site by all means.

Comment: That's what I want to do. When I look at the source of some websites, I see the format as in above, but I don't get the directory listing. The file was named "index.htm", and I tried "default.htm", but same thing. It hasn't been uploaded to a server, it's currently just a client-based website.

Comment: This is achieved via web server configuration (http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings for Apache) or manually generating directory listing. But, once again, doing so is basically asking for trouble. And "client-based website" is not a big consolation. Most of problems come from inside.

Answer (score 0):

PHPDL is a Php script that lists all the files in a directory (except itself of course). What sets PHPDL apart is that everything the script needs is in one file, including the file-type icons it uses.

Note: You can rename the script to anything you want. It will not list itself as a file to download.

This script safe and usefull, see demos:

http://greg-j.com/projects/phpdl/PHPDL-v2.php

http://greg-j.com/projects/phpdl/PHPDL-lite.php